# Regularly update UITableView

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, uitableview, nstimer

I have a UITableView which I need to update about 2-3 times a second via NSTimer. The cells in this table have UIButtons which respond to touchupinside. The problem is that this created extreme sensitivity. I could not press the button for too long otherwise it wouldn't register.

That issue was solved in
[UIButton oversensitive](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3929140/uibutton-oversensitive)

How can I solve the problem of regularly updating the table, while at the same time keeping the buttons responding naturally?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Update only the visible `UITableViewCells` instead of calling `reloadData` on the table. `reloadData` recreates the table cells each time it is called resulting in your touch events getting "lost" because they would go to the old deallocated table cells.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of reloading the contents in tableview, try to reload them in a table cell. Subclass the cell and reload the necessary data in a cell. By doing like this, your button will not be created again and again. Only the data will be refreshed.